# How to write find query that search for id in refrence?

Tags: mongoose, plugins, find

I'm using a Mongoose plugin, in which it **does not allow me to populate**, or **making chained queries**. The only option is to provide a `find` query object.

I have an ItemSchema:

```
{
    name: String,
    category: {
        ref: 'Category',
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    },
}
```

From the outside, I can perform the method:

```
this.ItemModel.paginate({
    query: {}, // find query options
    ... other options
});
```

It works OK. The problem is, I want it to return only certain items from a specific category, say from id `"5e0cb1b3c53e196514a30787"`

I have tried things below, but it does not work. Just return an empty array.

```
query: { 'category': id }
query: { 'category.$id': id }
query: { 'category': { $in: [id] } }
```

--

I'm using this plugin https://github.com/mixmaxhq/mongo-cursor-pagination

Answer (score 0):

OK I found out. Using `ObjectID` works:

```
     query: { category: new ObjectID(category) },
```